# Spring Data JPA could not determine type for property which is object of same class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a TestEntity and this entity can have a parent TestEntity. Spring Data JPA says Could not determine type for: abc.entity.TestEntity, at table: test_entity, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(parent)], How can I fix this? Didn't found something on the internet or I searched for the wrong thing.

```
package abc.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class TestEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    private TestEntity parent;

    public TestEntity(String name, TestEntity parent) {
        this.name = name;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public TestEntity getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put `@OneToOne` or `@ManyToOne` on `parent`.

Further you shall provide argument-less constructor.

Btw it is not spring data but the JPA provider who is giving you the error.

This question already has an answer here [JPA inheritance Could not determine type for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375782/jpa-inheritance-could-not-determine-type-for)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have got multiple `TestEntity` classes one with `abc.entity.TestEntity` package and the other with `tud.swt16w2.entity` package.

So `import` the correct Entity class i.e., `import tud.swt16w2.entity.TestEntity` as part of your repository class imports.

Comment: no i don't, I just wrongly edited the package name for stackoverflow. I fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `@ManyToOne` and `@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")` on your parent field.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Spring Data JPA complaining but Hibernate, the underlying OR Mapper. If you model a relationship to an entity (independent on whether it's the same type or a different entity) you need to qualify the cardinalities of the relationship, i.e. either annotate it with `@OneToOne` or `@ManyToOne` depending on which semantics you'd like to achieve.